# Duplicate identifier, subfig and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, subfloats, warnings

Why does LaTeX complain about `destination with the same identifier 
(name{subfigure.1.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored` with this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat { tikz draw (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm); }
\subfloat { tikz draw (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm); }
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat { tikz draw (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm); }
\subfloat { tikz draw (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm); }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Code works and produces four circles as it should. Error message disappear if I remove `hyperref`. Anyways, I would like to know what is happening here.

Comment: You need a caption, even it is empty- if you don't want a caption, then don't use a `subfloat`.

Comment: @cmhughes Ah, that was it. Caption to (whole) figure, not to subfigure. ...but why? Why no caption at all and `\caption{}` differs?

Comment: without a caption there is no increment in the `figure` (or `subfloat`, or whatever other number)- this is vital for the `hyperref` package to set its anchors uniquely, hence the duplication. If this turns out to be a satisfactory comment then I'll post it as an answer, but I'll wait a bit to see if a guru (maybe even the mighty Heiko) sees this question :)

Comment: @cmhughes OK. I will accept your answer as soon as you put it online.

Comment: @JoriMäntysalo It is simply how the `subfig` package is implemented, it does not expect a `figure` without `\caption`, and therefore this case is not handled. There is no particular reason for this, for example actual versions of the/my `subcaption` package should have no problems with sub-figures without main caption. (Sorry for the shameless self-praise.)

Answer (score 2):

When using the [`subfig`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subfig) package you need a `caption` even if it is empty. For example, the following code works without a warning:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat { tikz draw (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm); }
\subfloat { tikz draw (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm); }
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat { tikz draw (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm); }
\subfloat { tikz draw (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm); }
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As mentioned in the comments the [`subcaption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subcaption) does not suffer from this- personally I prefer this package, here's a complete MWE that demonstrates it

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        tikz draw (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm); 
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        tikz draw (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm); 
    \end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        tikz draw (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm); 
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        tikz draw (0cm,0cm) circle(1cm); 
    \end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```